# How to remove the index column title from a Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have this Dataframe and I want to remove the first '0' in the index column. I believe it's the index column name but not really sure.

```
0           nom hauteur    masse      prix impulsion specifique
0      Tondeuse     0.5     20.0    110.00                   80
1    Civic VTEC     2.0   3000.0   2968.00                  205
2  VelociRAPTOR     4.0   2000.0   6000.00                  250
3  La Puissance    12.0  15000.0  39000.00                  295
```

```
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(chemin_moteurs + '/' + 'moteur1.ppl', comment='#', sep='=', header=None, index_col=0).T
dataframe2 = pd.read_csv(chemin_moteurs + '/' + 'moteur2.ppl', comment='#', sep='=', header=None, index_col=0).T
dataframe3 = pd.read_csv(chemin_moteurs + '/' + 'moteur3.ppl', comment='#', sep='=', header=None, index_col=0).T
dataframe4 = pd.read_csv(chemin_moteurs + '/' + 'moteur4.ppl', comment='#', sep='=', header=None, index_col=0).T

moteurs = pd.concat([dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3, dataframe4], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You can rename a dataframe index using `df.index.names = ['Whatever']` where Whatever could be an empty string.

Comment: Apparently `column 0` of the csv-files is just row numbers starting from 0. When reading in, any column set as index would be "moved" to the first position, keeping its name (if it has one) or index number. Generic index doesn't have one initially so you may try chaining `.reset_index(drop=True)` when reading csv.